# This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I know this has been asked a million times before on StackOverflow and I tried all the solutions but this only started to occur after I added the Android support library jar to my libs folder and I recently added a view like such below:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/white"
              android:id="@id/viewPager"
        >
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Here's the error log I'm getting:

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90)
    at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:149)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:167)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:583)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:528)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$6.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:523)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have my Preview version set at Nexus 5 and Android API 19 (Android 4.4.2)

I am running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 13.1. This problem did not previously occur before I added the support library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have IntelliJ Ultimate 13.1.4 and the rendering did not work.

All I had to do was the following:

`Help > Check for Updates` and then choose to Upgrade to 13.1.5 (free) and the rendering for the views works.

I was inspired by this post here:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127027

Answer (score 2):

Try IntelliJ 14 EAP or wait for the final release.

> The issue is that JetBrains hasn't updated IntelliJ 13 as required. It has been fixed in IntelliJ 14 EAP but the fix hasn't been ported back to 13.

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=74873)

Comment: Hm I don't think I can upgrade. My company purchased a license for Ultimate 13.1 recently. I assumed this was the latest version. Is the upgrade to Ultimate 14 free? Thanks!

Comment: Oh wait, I found a solution. I will update with proper answer for other people. Thank you so much for your source or else I would have not found the answer in the tracker!

Comment: Good to know, that it was fixed in 13.1.5! BTW - IntelliJ licenses include updates for 1 year, so you will be able to upgrade to 14 for free ;)

Comment: I have IntelliJ 14 and the same problem.